Can we render and generate multiple .docx files with docxtemplater and output them as one .zip file?
I have had no issue creating multiple functions that geenrate .docx documents using the docxtemplater library.
However, below I have created two instances of "docxtemplater", rendered and generated both files, and then added them to a Pizzip instance. Finally, I have tried to saveAs this instance as a zip file.
The function is working and the output is a zip file with two .docx documents. Unfortunately, the files will not open as "they are not valid".
import Docxtemplater from "docxtemplater";
import PizZip from "pizzip";
import PizZipUtils from "pizzip/utils";
import { saveAs } from "file-saver";
import expressionParser from "docxtemplater/expressions";
import JSZip from "jszip";

const storage = getStorage();



//New zip instance
const outputZip = new PizZip();
function loadFile(url, callback) {
  PizZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, callback);
}

export const renderRelianceForms = async () => {
  try {
    await getDownloadURL(ref(storage, "RS1PD.docx")).then((url) => {
      loadFile(url, function (error, content) {
        if (error) {
          throw error;
        }

        const zip = new PizZip(content);
        const doc = new Docxtemplater(zip, { paragraphLoop: true, linebreaks: true, parser: expressionParser });

        doc.render({
        //   date: referral?.creation_date.toDate().toLocaleDateString(),
        });
        const out = doc.getZip().generate({
          type: "arraybuffer",
          compression: "DEFLATE",
          mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
        });

        outputZip.file("Reliance Section 1 - Personal Details.docx", out, { base64: true });
        console.log("success", out);
      });
    });

    await getDownloadURL(ref(storage, "RS1MP.docx")).then((url) => {
      loadFile(url, function (error, content) {
        if (error) {
          throw error;
        }

        const zip = new PizZip(content);
        const doc = new Docxtemplater(zip, { paragraphLoop: true, linebreaks: true, parser: expressionParser });
        doc.render({
        //   date: referral?.creation_date.toDate().toLocaleDateString(),
        });
        const out = doc.getZip().generate({
          type: "arraybuffer",
          compression: "DEFLATE",
          mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
        });

        outputZip.file("Reliance Section 1 - Missing Person Form.docx", out, { base64: true });
        console.log("success", out);
      });
    });

    //OUTZIP
    const output = outputZip.generate({
      type: "blob",
      compression: "DEFLATE",
      mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
    });

    console.log(outputZip);
    saveAs(output, "Reliance.zip");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};

I have used the code from an answer in this question, and its working up until I try to open my newly saved file:
How do I create a zip file with multiple docx files generated by the "docxtemplater"?
And also researched from this question below: I tried to generate() both the .docx and final output (.zip file) with no parameters and even included {base64:true} to no avail.
How can I output a docx from docxtemplater.js for input in jszip

I have resolved this issue.
The following case of rendering multiple docx files and saving them into one .zip file will work if yu follow the answer to the question below with the changes ive mentioned below the link:
How do I create a zip file with multiple docx files generated by the "docxtemplater"?

Remove the "compression:DEFLATE" option from .generate() in all instances and for the final output zip.

Change JSZip to Pizzip.


